# Ember: store.update updates all attributes?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm creating a real time multiplayer textual game in Ember.js.
So far very exciting, but I'm running a little problem.

I have a `game` model which looks a bit like this:

```
App.Game = DS.Model.extend({
    numbers: DS.attr(),
    drawnNumbers: DS.attr(), // array
    gameStatus: DS.attr(),
    table: DS.belongsTo('table'),
    bingoCards: DS.hasMany('bingoCard', { async: true })
});
```

My controller looks like this (leaving out unnecessary information):

```
App.GameController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    gameBingoCards: function () {
        var gameId;
        gameId = this.get('id');

        console.log("inside gameBingoCards");            

        return this.get('store').filter('bingoCard', function (bingoCard) {
            return (bingoCard.get('game.id') === gameId);
        });
    }.property('model.bingoCards'),
    ownBingoCards: function () {
        var gameId, userId;
        gameId = this.get('id');
        userId = this.get('session.content.id');

        console.log("inside ownBingoCards");          

        return this.get('store').filter('bingoCard', function (bingoCard) {
            return (bingoCard.get('game.id') === gameId && bingoCard.get('user.id') === userId);
        });
    }.property('gameBingoCards.[]'),

    gameMessages: function () {
        var gameId;
        gameId = this.get('id');

        console.log("gameMessages");

        return this.get('store').filter('message', function (message) {
            return (message.get('game.id') === gameId);
        });
    }.property('model.messages'),
});
```

In the view I render the cards:

```
{{#each bingoCard in ownBingoCards}}
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <span class="label label-primary">Card {{bingoCard.id}}</span>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-card">
            <tbody>
            {{#each row in bingoCard.squares}}
                 <!-- displaying the numbers here -->
            {{/each}}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

Whenever the game updates I update the store like this:

```
record = serializer.extractSingle(store, type, data);
// record looks like this:
// {id: "538c56843800226245c3621a", gameStatus: "idle"} 
store.update("game", record);
```

If I open the console I get the following:

```
inside ownBingoCards GameController.js:102
inside gameBingoCards GameController.js:32
inside ownBingoCards GameController.js:102
```

Note: the game receives many updates during the game, so every time all the cards get rerendered. How can I prevent this?

edit:

After I reload the page on that specific game route it only goes inside ownBingoCards and gameBingoCards once and it doesn't re-render everytime after an update.

edit2:

The gameMessages attribute also only gets called once, why does the gameBingoCards keep getting called?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I've fixed it after countless hours.

My route looked like this:

```
model: function (params) {
    return this.store.find('game', params.game_id);
},
setupController: function (controller, model) {
    model.reload();

    controller.set('model', model);
},
```

And I've changed it to this:

```
model: function (params) {
    return this.store.find('game', params.game_id);
},
setupController: function (controller, model) {
    model.reload();

    controller.set('model', model);
    controller.set('modelBingoCards', model.get('bingoCards'));
    controller.set('modelMessages', model.get('messages'));
},
```

Plus I also changed the property listeners to `.property('modelMessages')` and `.property('modelBingoCards')`.

Could any please tell me why this worked?